# What kind of usability testing can I perform when the final users of the product are developers?

Tags: test-design

I have built a framework aimed at developers and I'd like to carry out a test with users. However, since my **final users are developers**, I don't know how to approach this testing. The usual list of tasks to perform doesn't seem appropriate in this context.

*Some context about the tool:*

There are several APIs out there having a similar functionality but being different enough so it's not trivial to use them together. I've developed a framework that allows the user to forget about this integration, focusing on the results returned by the APIs combined. 
This way, developers don't need to spend too much time integrating the different APIs into their system, they just need to implement a common interface (if it's not implemented yet), launch my framework in a server of their choice and send their requests to it.

Considering this, is there any kind of test which fits best for this situation?

In the end, I want to test if using my system is a better/easier alternative to integrate the APIs by hand. I don't know if I should make a list of tasks to accomplish using the tool and then ask some questions, or if I should make someone code something using the API and without using it and compare the resulting codes (checking static code metrics, for instance), etc.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "The usual list of tasks to perform doesn't seem appropriate in this context." why not?

Comment: @globalworming so I would just give the developer a task of things to code using the framework? And how should I assess that code? I'm pretty much lost here

Comment: @J.Maria: How would you assess the result of a task in a field that you are unfamiliar with? Would it be a possibility that the users themselves give a score on the usability aspects you want to test?

Comment: What do you mean *"assess that code"*? You haven't mentioned what you are trying to *learn* from this testing. If there are tasks that this framework is supposed to help with, why *not* get developers to perform those using it?

Comment: Hi @BartvanIngenSchenau. I've edited the question to give more information. The thing is that I don't know how to measure the usability here, the only idea I had was the one that jonrsharpe mentions, about checking how the framework help developers to do something, but I don't know how to compare that, how difficult is for them to do something with and without the framework.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That was what I thought at the beginning, but how can I compare how difficult is to do something with and without the tool I've made?

Comment: You say *"don't spend too much time"*, so perhaps whether it's quicker? But what was your *hypothesis* for building this, you should be measuring against that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the initial hypothesis was that it would be much more straightforward and quicker to integrate those technologies in a new app by using this framework than doing it by hand. In this case, should I prepare a list of tasks so developers build something, like a demo, using the framework and not using it and then measuring how long does it take them to finish both demos?

Comment: I don't know how you'd measure straightforwardness so focussing on time will have to do; you could ask qualitative questions about ease of use compared to the previous method, but be careful not to be leading. You'll have to do multiple tasks, as the earlier usages will be biased by extra time spent learning a new thing, which you would expect to be amortised over time saved on future tasks once you've learned it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93999/discussion-between-j-maria-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: @jonrsharpe could you add your comments as an answer? I think you deserve the credit for your help and for being the first one in offering the answer, even if it was in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting task. You could run two usability tests with developers:

- one with developers using APIs
- one with developers using your framework

and collect *statistics* (like satisfaction on Likert scale) and *feedback* on challenges (from think-aloud protocols) from both of them and compare. You care about both *quantitative* data (how good your framework was) as well as *qualitative* results (at what parts it was better and where it still needs some improvement and why). I once collected a lot of useful feedback about Web service search engine by just sitting together with 16 developers (in a separate 16 sessions) as they were using the assigned search engine to find a Web service and listening what they want to do and what they struggle with (this is form of thinking-aloud protocol).

There are many parts that contribute to how *usable* an API or framework is: design/architecture, examples, documentation, IDE support. [Microsoft has performed usability tests](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/measuring-api-usability/184405654) for one of their libraries.

I have also ask similar question about this topic [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/38286/do-testers-perform-usability-tests-of-api).

Answer (score 0):

Any kind of `Beta` testing is what you are looking for. How you approach that is totally up to you. Some of the options:

1. Organize a Hackathon ask people to use the framework,
2. Maybe you can find a local community of programmers to which you can present the framework and ask them to use it (Where I come from there are some local `Java` user groups that meet on occasions),
3. If you do not mind the bigger public - find some internet community that brings together people that tend to use those APIs (internet forum, reddit, maybe somewhere on Stack),
4. Use it yourself - I know it is not the 'best' solution, but 'giving it a go' might help you understand its limitations (this, I guess, classifies as `Alpha` testing)

Then collect the feedback, simply ask people what they liked about the framework, what is missing from it, what they would improve. Once your `Beta` group is big enough you can do some static code anlysis and see which methods were prefered over the others.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I gather that you are making a sub-product that can be integrated into a larger product and creates an adaptation layer to unify several other APIs. The usability metric that you want to test is the ease of creating a system that includes your product compared to creating a system that doesn't.

Usability in this sense is not what is normally meant when people talk about usability testing. What you really are asking is how well does your product meet its purpose and that can only be really tested by putting it out in the wild and seeing how well it gets adopted by your target audience.

You can get early feedback by using it yourself, for example to create a demo system to show others what the possibilities are, and by asking experienced developers in the field you are targeting to try your product and asking them what needs to be changed/improved before they would recommend it for their next project.